# Eloquent: Select field from whereHas block fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have got a slightly complex SQL query using a combination of `where`, `whereHas`, `orWhereHas` etc.

Everything goes well but when I add `'custom_records.custom_title'` (see below) into the Select fields it fails with:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Any ideas?
Here it's the snippet: 
`

```
$record = $this->record->newQuery();`

 $record->whereHas('customRecords', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('custom_title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        });

 return $record->get([
            'records.id',
            'records.another_field',
            'records.another_field_2',
            'custom_records.custom_title',
        ]);
```

**Update**
When I run the produced SQL query on a mysql client it comes back with:

```
Unknown column 'custom_records.custom_title',' in 'field list'
```

Comment: try `dd($record->get([
            'records.id',
            'records.another_field',
            'records.another_field_2',
            'custom_records.custom_title',
        ]))` and you will get response where you can see what's happening

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze It does not help too much, I am afraid.

Comment: Doesn't your table names have to match? Shouldn't it be `customRecords.custom_title` for the last field?

Comment: @ourmandave `customRecords` is the name of the `hasMany` method in `Record` model. `custom_records ` is the table name

Comment: @ourmandave as I see `customRecords` is column name and `custom_records` is table name

Comment: You can't select `custom_records.custom_title` like that. Since it's a `HasMany` relationship, there can be multiple `custom_records` per `record`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir That's the correct answer. If you want add a new answer so to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select `custom_records.custom_title` like that. Since it's a `HasMany` relationship, there can be multiple `custom_records` per `record`.

You have to do something like this:

```php
$callback = function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
    $query->where('custom_title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
};
Record::whereHas('customRecords', $callback)
    ->with(['customRecords' => $callback])
    ->get(['id', 'another_field', 'another_field_2']);
```